# How can I clear the latest sharing history in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

How can I clear the sharing history in Windows 8?

For example I was doing a webcast, when I shared a picture, it showed the latest email recipients I sent. This is unacceptable for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to clear your previous history:

[Windows 8: Clear Previous Searches](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22474/windows-8-clear-previous-searches/)

> 1. Move your mouse to the bottom right of the screen then move it up to access the Charms bar. Click Settings.
> 2. Choose More PC settings.
> 3. When the PC settings screen appears, choose the Search section from the left side.
> 4. The History section can be found at the top of the screen. This section allows you to Delete history or turn the history feature off.
> 5. When you click Delete history, a small message will appear next to the button to tell you that all previous search keywords have been
>      deleted.
> 6. Using the slider, you can completely disable the system’s remembrance of these search terms. If you turn the History feature
>      off, the Delete history button will be grayed out too.

Comment: Perfect! There is a clear history in the sharing pane, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Charms Bar -> More PC Settings

On the left, from the **PC Settings** section select **History**

Finally click on **Delete History**

You may choose to turn off History feature altogether by setting **Let Windows save my searches as future search suggestions.** to **Off**

Comment: Not search, is sharing